# Did FBSDKShareKit replace FBSDKMessengerShareKit?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk-4.0

I'm a newbie at Objective-C and iOS stuff, not to mention the Facebook iOS SDK, so I had a hard time researching what is going on with the difference between FBSDKMessengerShareKit and FBSDKShareKit.  However, the CocoaPods guide says FBSDKMessengerShareKit is Deprecated - `This Library is Deprecated` - https://cocoapods.org/pods/FBSDKMessengerShareKit - but no other info is given.

The reason I'm asking this is because I'm working on a project that has both FBSDKShareKit and FBSDKMessengerShareKit in the Podfile, and I need to update FBSDKShareKit, so I'm wondering:

1) Do I need to worry about also updating FBSDKMessengerShareKit, or

2) Should I remove FBSDKMessengerShareKit if it's deprecated, or could it still be providing functionality to the app even though it's deprecated?

3) Where can I find documentation for the FBSDKMessengerShareKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to update FBSDKShareKit to the latest version, you should remove the deprecated SDK.

To elaborate, the difference between FBSDKShareKit and MessengerKit is that MessengerKit has been deprecated in favor of FBSDKShareKit, which now also contains Messenger component.

Below link shows a comprehensive guide to implementing Messenger using the updated SDK. (Specifically look at **Prerequisites** section)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/messenger/

Comment: Thanks for the help